# Find string pattern from end

Tags: php

I am trying to find if a string is of a format `<initial_part_of_name>_0.pdf` i.e.

1. Find if it ends with `.pdf` (could be eliminated using `rtrim`)
2. The initial part is followed by an `_` underscore.
3. The underscore is followed by a whole number (0, 1, 2, ... , etc.)

What could be the optimum way to achieve this? I have tried combinations of the string functions `strpos` (to find the position. but could not get to do anything from the end of the string).
Any pointers would be appreciated!

**Edit:**
Sample strings:
`public://Big_Data_Tutorial_part4_0.pdf`
`public://Big_Data_Tutorial_part4_1.pdf`
`public://Big_Data_Tutorial_part4_3.pdf`
The reason why I need to check is to avoid duplicate files which are stored with the `_<number>` appended.

Comment: what does the initial part looks like?? can you give few full examples so the pattern is more clear??

Comment: @Andrew Added in the sample strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a non-array and regex way

```
$str1 = "public://Big_Data_Tutorial_part4_0a.pdf"; // no match because 0a
$str2 = "public://Big_Data_Tutorial_part4_1.pdf"; // match
$str3 = "public://Big_Data_Tutorial_part4_3.pdf"; // match


$last_part = strrchr($str1, "_");

if (trim(strstr($last_part, ".", true), "_0..9") == "" && strstr($last_part, ".") == ".pdf") {
    echo "match";
}
```

Comment: I would prefer this solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `preg_match()` function for matching patterns

Check the function [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
preg_match("/(.*)_(\d+)\.pdf$/", "<initial_part_of_name>_0.pdf",$arr);
```

In `$arr[1]`, you will get the `<initial_part_of_name>`

in `$arr[2]`, you will get the number after underscore

Comment: If you want to check only that the string matches to that pattern then, you can check like if(preg_match("/(.*)_(\d+)\.pdf$/", "<initial_part_of_name>_450a.pdf")) {...}

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '<initial_part_of_name>_0.pdf';

$exploded = explode('.', $str);

echo $exploded[1];
```

Comment: @AjitS the array starts at 0, not 1, 0 is indeed <initial... but 1 is the .pdf. (or what ever extension after the dot).

Comment: The only issue could be if there is another dot in the filename.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't undelete the comment. I cannot use this as there might be dots in the string. Also, it does not help matching the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using regex. Something like

`^[0-9A-Za-z]+\_[\d]\.pdf$`

**Implementation:**

```
$filename = '<initial_part_of_name>_0.pdf';

if(preg_match('/^[0-9A-Za-z]+\_[\d]\.pdf$/i', $filename)){
    // name pattern Matched
}
```

**SOLUTION 2**

use `pathinfo()`

```
$filename = '<initial_part_of_name>_0.pdf';
$path_parts = pathinfo($filename);

if(strtolower($path_parts['extension']) == 'pdf') {
    if(preg_match('/.*_[\d]$/', $path_parts['filename'])){
        // name pattern Matched
    }
} else {
    // Not a PDF file
}
```

Comment: Fails if the name is `Big_Data_Tutorial_part4_0.pdf`

Comment: Second solution wont fail. try it.